# Indexing text file for microcontroller

Tags: algorithm, performance, indexing

I need to search for a specific record in a large file. The search will be performed on a microprocessor (ESP8266), so I'm working with limited storage and RAM.

The list looks like this:

```
BSSID,data1,data2
001122334455,float,float
001122334466,float,float
...
```

I was thinking using an index to speed up the search. The data are static, and the index will be built on a computer and then loaded onto the microcontroller.

What I've done so far is very simplistic.
I created an index of the first byte of the BSSID and points at the first and last values with that BSSID prefix.

The performance is terrible, but the index file is very small and uses very little RAM.  I though to go further with this method, taking a look at the first two bytes, but the index table will be 256 times larger, resulting in a table 1/3 the size of the data file.

This is the index with the first method:

```
00,0000000000,0000139984
02,0000139984,0000150388
04,0000150388,0000158812
06,0000158812,0000160900
08,0000160900,0000171160
```

What indexing algorithm do you suggest that I use?

EDIT:
Sorry I didn't include enough background before.
I'm storing the data and index file on the flash memory of the chip. I have at the moment 30000 records, but this number could potentially grow until the chips momery limit is hit.  The set is indeed static when is stored on the microcontroller but could be updated in a second moment with the help of a computer.
The data isn't spread simmetrically between indexes.
My goal is to find a good compromise between search speed, index size and RAM used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're stuck, but I *can* comment on what you've done so far.

Most of all, the way to determine the "best" method is to

- define "best" for your purposes;
- research indexing algorithms (basic ones have been published for over 50 years);
- choose a handful to implement;
- Evaluate those implementations according to your definition of "best".

Keep in mind your basic resource restriction: you have limited RAM.  If method requires more RAM than you have, it doesn't work, and is therefore *infinitely* slower than any method that does work.

You've come close to a critical idea, however: you want your index table to expand to consume any free RAM, using that space as effectively as possible.  If you can index 16 bits instead of 8 and still fit the table comfortably into your available space, then you've cut down your linear search time by roughly a factor of 256.

---

**Indexing considerations**

Don't put the ending value in each row: it's identical to the starting value in the next row.  Omit that, and you save one word in each row of the table, giving you twice the table room.

Will you get better performance if you slice the file into equal parts (same quantity of BSSIDS for each row of your table), and then store the entire starting BSSID with its record number?  If your BSSIDs are heavily clumped, this might improve your overall processing, even though your table had fewer rows.  You can't use a direct index in this case; you have to search the first column to get the proper starting point.

---

Does that move you toward a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much memory you got (I am not familiar with that MCU) but do not forget that these tables are static/constant so they can be stored in **EEPROM** instead of **RAM** some chips have quite a lot of **EEPROM** usually way more than **RAM**...

Assume your file is sorted by the index. So You you got (assuming 32bit address) per each entry:

```cpp
BYTE ix, DWORD beg,DWORD end
```

Why not this:

```cpp
struct entry { DWORD beg,end };
entry ix0[256];
```

Where the first BYTE is also address in index array. This will spare 1 Byte per entry
Now as **Prune** suggested you can ignore the end address as you will scan the following entries in file anyway until you hit the correct index or index with different first `BYTE`. so yo can use:

```cpp
DWORD ix[256];
```

where yo have only start address `beg`.

Now we do not know how many entries you actually have nor how many entries will share the same second `BYTE` of index. So we can not do any further assumption to improve...

You wanted to do something like:

```cpp
DWORD ix[65536];
```

But have not enough memory for it ... how about doing something like this instead:

```cpp
const N=1024; // number of entries you can store
const dix=(max_index_value+1)/N;
const ix[N]={.....};
```

so each entry `ix[i]` will cover all the indexes from `i*dix` to `((i+1)*dix)-1`. So to find `index` you do this:

```cpp
i = ix[index/dix];
for (;i<file_size;)
 {
 read entry from file at i-th position;
 update position i;
 if (file_index==index) { do your stuff; break; }
 if (file_index> index) { index not found;  break; }
 }
```

To improve performance you can rewrite this linear scan into binary search between address of `ix[index/dix]`  and `ix[(index/dix)+1]` or file size for the last index ... assuming each entry in file has the same size ...

Comment: Thanks! That help me a lot. I thought the bssid as text instead of number, that made a lot of difference.

Comment: @MatteoGottardi glad to be of help. Yes in such case you got just `10` possible occurrences instead of `256` for the same table size resulting in ~25.5 times worse performance too ...